# rename same file on specific directory using java

Tags: java, r.java-file

first of all thanks for your time,

I need to replace the name of the same file in a specific directory(TEMP). My problem is, i have x number of same files whose structure is as follows: timestamp_filename.txt and i need to replace this structure to filename_count.txt.

for example i have two files with timestamp_file.txt, and i want to replace this by file.txt and file_1.txt.

get all the files is not something that can be done because the temp folder can grow much.

Thanks

Comment: Open a directory stream to iterate/loop over all the files in the chosen directory. Then use the move method on the files to rename them appropiately. Check this link out for help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a FilenameFilter object in conjunction with a regular expression to retrieve a list of the matching files in your temp folder.
2. Then sort the result list using a custom comparator so that all files with the same 'file' part but different 'timestamp' parts are next to each other (to simplify the generation of the _1, _2, ... versions).
3. Then iterate through your result list, renaming/moving files appropriately.

Here's a sample filename filter that uses a regular expression to match file names:

```
public class REFilenameFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    /** The regular expression to use when matching file names. */
    final String regularExpression;


    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param expression the regular expression to use when matching file names.
     */
    public REFilenameFilter(final String expression) {
        regularExpression = expression;
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if the file matches the regular expression.
     *
     * @param dir the directory containing the file.
     * @param name the name of the file.
     * @return true if the name of the file matches the regular expression, otherwise false.
     */
    public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
        // return true if the name matches the regular expression
        return name.matches(regularExpression);
    }

}
```

Here's a sample comparator (assuming your timestamp is just a long):

```
public class TempFileComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    public int compare(final File file1, final File file2) {
        String[] parts1 = file1.getName().split("_");
        String[] parts2 = file2.getName().split("_");

        int comp = parts1[1].compareTo(parts2[1]);
        if(comp == 0) {
            Long timestamp1 = Long.parseLong(parts1[0]);
            Long timestamp2 = Long.parseLong(parts2[0]);
            comp = timestamp1.compareTo(timestamp2);
        }

        return comp;
    }

}
```